# updating a progressbar while streaming a mp3 file in android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

**What i have:**
*I have a media player code that buffers song perfectly for a  link below*

<`R.string.testsong_20_sec`>**Link**:: `Its a song hosted in google drive`

**SingleSongBuffering.java**

```
public class SingleSongBuffering extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnTouchListener, OnCompletionListener, OnBufferingUpdateListener{
    private ImageButton buttonPlayPause;
    private SeekBar seekBarProgress;
    public EditText editTextSongURL;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private int mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds; // this value contains the song duration in milliseconds. Look at getDuration() method in MediaPlayer class
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.single_song_buffering);
        initView();
    }
    /** This method initialise all the views in project*/
    private void initView() {
        buttonPlayPause = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ButtonTestPlayPause);
        buttonPlayPause.setOnClickListener(this);
        seekBarProgress = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.SeekBarTestPlay);
        seekBarProgress.setMax(99); // It means 100% .0-99
        seekBarProgress.setOnTouchListener(this);
        editTextSongURL = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditTextSongURL);
        editTextSongURL.setText(R.string.testsong_20_sec);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    }
    /** Method which updates the SeekBar primary progress by current song playing position*/
    private void primarySeekBarProgressUpdater() {
        seekBarProgress.setProgress((int)(((float)mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()/mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds)*100)); // This math construction give a percentage of "was playing"/"song length"
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(notification,1000);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.ButtonTestPlayPause){
            /** ImageButton onClick event handler. Method which start/pause mediaplayer playing */
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(editTextSongURL.getText().toString()); // setup song from http://www.hrupin.com/wp-content/uploads/mp3/testsong_20_sec.mp3 URL to mediaplayer data source
                mediaPlayer.prepare(); // you must call this method after setup the datasource in setDataSource method. After calling prepare() the instance of MediaPlayer starts load data from URL to internal buffer.
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds = mediaPlayer.getDuration(); // gets the song length in milliseconds from URL
            if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                mediaPlayer.start();
                buttonPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_pause);
            }else {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                buttonPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_play);
            }
            primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.SeekBarTestPlay){
            /** Seekbar onTouch event handler. Method which seeks MediaPlayer to seekBar primary progress position*/
            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                SeekBar sb = (SeekBar)v;
                int playPositionInMillisecconds = (mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds / 100) * sb.getProgress();
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(playPositionInMillisecconds);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        /** MediaPlayer onCompletion event handler. OMethod which calls then song playing is complete*/
        buttonPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_play);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
        /** Method which updates the SeekBar secondary progress by current song loading from URL position*/
        seekBarProgress.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
    }
}
```

---

**What is working:**
I am able to stream the song and play/pause the song

**What is not working:**
Progress bar part is not working !
1. progress bar is not updating its in the end of the progress line from the beginning itself

**What i want:**
Progress bar part to work so that i can drag the progress so that song plays from that point

***HOW TO RESOLVE THIS  ?***

---

Comment: post url which you are using...

Answer (score 0):

> Progress bar part is not working ! 1. progress bar is not updating its
>   in the end of the progress line from the beginning itself

** After testing 2 to 3 urls.

Buffer listner will not give percentage if the track(url) which is assigned to MediaPlayer data source is not giving track information.

You can test it like : after setting datasource (url) for streaming once mediaplyer start paying check is that mediaplayer trackDuration(mPlayer.getDuration) is giving correct duration of that track ?

Because if the track duration is not correct thn buffering level will also b not correct.

So the problem may b from the track not with the progress bar

in below code one url is with the track details which is providing track duraiton once player is prepared and started(checked in `onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)`)

And onr url which is not giving track information.

check the comments given in code

Hope i got your question correctly. let me know if i have not ..

```
  private MediaPlayer mPlayer;

    private void playMusic() {
        try {
            mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            // For testing purpose added below url
            /**
             * Its not like mp3 or particular coded url will return duration and track info.
             * streaming url should also provide details.
             * 
             * mPlayer.setDataSource("http://50.117.115.210/");
             * 
             * Url which is not providing track details and other information,so
             * here we are not getting track duration and bcz of that buffering
             * update will not be correct.
             * 
             * */
            /**
             * mPlayer.setDataSource("http://www.samisite.com/sound/cropShadesofGrayMonkees.mp3");
             * This is providing correct details of the track which is going to play.
             * 
             */
            mPlayer.setDataSource("http://www.samisite.com/sound/cropShadesofGrayMonkees.mp3");
            mPlayer.prepareAsync();
            mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mPlayer.start();

                }
            });
            mPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

                public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
                    // Media player will required Track's information to give
                    // you buffering percentage. So once check after starting
                    // player are you getting track duration from
                    // MediaPlayer.getDuration()

                    Log.e("onBufferingUpdate", "" + percent);
                    seekBar.setSecondaryProgress(percent);

                    // *****
                    // Buffering update will be correct if mp.getDuration() > 0
                    // double ratio = percent / 100.0;
                    // int bufferingpercent = (int) (mp.getDuration() * ratio);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private OnSeekBarChangeListener seekbarListner = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            if (fromUser) {
                if (mPlayer != null) {
                    if (progress <= seekBar.getSecondaryProgress()) {
                    } else {
                        seekBar.setProgress(progress);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    };
```